# How to see the docker state instead of interacting with the shell?

Tags: docker

I use following command to build web server

```
docker run --name webapp -p 8080:4000 mypyweb
```

When it stopped and I want to restart, I always use:

```
sudo docker start webapp && sudo docker exec -it webapp bash
```

But I can't see the server state as the first time:

```
Digest: sha256:e61b45be29f72fb119ec9f10ca660c3c54c6748cb0e02a412119fae3c8364ecd

Status: Downloaded newer image for ericgoebelbecker/stackify-tutorial:1.00

* Running on http://0.0.0.0:4000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

How can I see the state instead of interacting with the shell?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `docker run`, the default behavior is to run the container detached. This runs in the background and is detached from your shell's stdin/out.

To run the container in the foreground and connected to stdin/out:

```sh
docker run --interactive --tty --publish=8080:4000 mypyweb
```

To `docker start` a container, similarly:

```sh
docker start --interactive --attach [CONTAINER]
```

**NB** `--attach` rather than `-tty`

You may list (all add `--all`) running containers:

```sh
docker container ls
```

E.g. I ran Nginx:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  PORTS                 NAMES
7cc4b4e1cfd6  nginx  0.0.0.0:8888->80/tcp  nostalgic_thompson
```

**NB** You may use the `NAME` or any uniquely identifiable subset of the `ID` to reference the container 
Then:

```sh
docker stop nostalgic_thompson
docker start --interative --attach 7cc4
```

You may check the container's logs (when running detached or from another shell) by grabbing the container's `ID` or `NAMES`

```sh
docker logs nostalgic_thompson
docker logs 7cc4
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Using `docker exec` is causing the shell to attach to the container. If you are comparing the behavior of `docker run` versus `docker start`, they behave differently, and it *is* confusing. Try this:

```
$ sudo docker start -a webapp
```

the `-a` flag tells docker to attach `stdout/stderr` and forward signals.

There are some other switches you can use with the `start` command (and a huge number for the `run` command). You can run `docker [command] --help` to get a summary of the options.

One other command that you might want to use is `logs` which will show the console output logs for a running container:

```
$ docker ps
[find the container ID]
$ docker logs [container ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think your container's misbehaving, it's often not wrong to just delete it and create a new one.

```
docker rm webapp
docker run --name webapp -p 8080:4000 mypyweb
```

Containers occasionally have more involved startup sequences and these can assume they're generally starting from a clean slate.  It should also be extremely routine to delete and recreate a container; it's required for some basic tasks like upgrading the image underneath a container to a newer version or changing published ports or environment variables.

`docker exec` probably shouldn't be part of your core workflow, any more than you'd open a shell to interact with your Web browser.  I generally don't tend to `docker stop` containers, except to immediately `docker rm` them.